# Trying to make an array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm having a tough time creating a an array that holds objects of a class I made. I cannot use std::vector to hold the objects so here is what I tried to do:

This is my cpp file:
Resistor.cpp:

```
#include "Resistor.h"   
Resistor::Resistor(int rIndex_, string name_, double resistance_){
    int rIndex = rIndex_;
    name = name_;
    resistance = resistance_;       
}
```

I'm trying to make an array of these Resistor objects in another cpp file:
Rparser.cpp:

```
#include "Resistor.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Rparser.h"

Rparser::Rparser(int maxNodes_, int maxResistors_){
    maxNodes = maxNodes_;
    maxResistors = maxResistors_;
    resistorArray = new Resistor[maxResistors_];   //trying to make an array   
}
```

My Rparser.h file looks like this, as you can see I declared a pointer that points to Resistor datatype:

```
#include "Resistor.h"
#include "Node.h"
class Rparser{
public:
    int maxNodes;
    int maxResistors;
    Resistor *resistorArray;  //declared a pointer here

    Rparser(int maxNodes_, int maxResistors_);
    ~Rparser(){};
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Resistor::Resistor()’
note: candidates are: Resistor::Resistor(int, std::string, double, int*)
note:                 Resistor::Resistor(const Resistor&)
```

Why is it treating the line `resistorArray = new Resistor[maxResistors]`
as a function call instead of creating an array?

Comment: Because there are (multiple) function calls: The constructors. As long as you don't have a constructor without parameter, you can't create objects without parameters. [This isn't Java. An array is not "n places where are object could be, but initially empty" but "n objects"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Resistor` constructor that takes no arguments (that is what the compiler is telling you in the error message, it is not a function call, but a call to the no arguments constructor.). Think about it, `new Resistor[]` specifies no constructor arguments.